# Skip ahead in Windows Media Player embedded webpage object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-media-player

I have an embedded Windows Media Player object in my website and I'd like to make it skip ahead to a certain point when the page loads. Most sites suggest using:

```
mediaplayerID.controls.currentPosition=xxx
```

That works great in Chrome but IE throws up a JavaScript error saying that mediaplayerID is undefined. I assume the issue is that the script is running before the media player object is fully loaded -- after the video starts playing, I can run set the currentPosition in the Developer Tools console and it skips ahead like it should. Is there a way in JavaScript to detect when (or wait until) media player is loaded and then change position?